# Node JS trigger function on my web page

Tags: php, html, ajax, node.js

Using node js I wanted to execute the function on a specific web page.
It's like the server will just visit the page to run the function.
How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Using cron job of node JS, I need to generate reports(made from javascript) and send it in a weekly basis.

Comment: So you want to prepare the data in your javascript call to your page to get the html and return it as a report?

Comment: Exactly and converting it into a PDF file that attach in the email.

Comment: Your server can not visit a page. Your page has to do that. Just check back with the server in intervals and let the server decide if its time to execute something...

Answer (score 0):

you can make  a GET request to your page using the [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) get the html as result and then convert it in your node.js application to PDF